# Java RestApi Jersey exception HTTP Status 500

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

I try to implement simple REST-based Web service but get this exception:

HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception

[Exception part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPqrL.png)
[Exception part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LlY5.png)

**my pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>CC2016_task1</groupId>
  <artifactId>CC2016_task1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**my web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CC2016</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/crunchify/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**my java class**

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/ftocservice")
public class FtoCService {

      @GET
      @Produces("application/json")
      public Response convertFtoC() throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        Double fahrenheit = 98.24;
        Double celsius;
        celsius = (fahrenheit - 32)*5/9; 
        jsonObject.put("F Value", fahrenheit); 
        jsonObject.put("C Value", celsius);

        String result = "@Produces(\"application/json\") Output: \n\nF to C Converter Output: \n\n" + jsonObject;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
      }

      @Path("{f}")
      @GET
      @Produces("application/json")
      public Response convertFtoCfromInput(@PathParam("f") float f) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        float celsius;
        celsius =  (f - 32)*5/9; 
        jsonObject.put("F Value", f); 
        jsonObject.put("C Value", celsius);

        String result = "@Produces(\"application/json\") Output: \n\nF to C Converter Output: \n\n" + jsonObject;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
      }
```

Can someone help me fix this problem ? thanks